# Checkbox in Pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

Below is my code which works fine. But I would like it to work even if checkbox is not present in the application. Is there any way to check for the checkbox and if present check the checkbox otherwise do some other actions.

```
app = Application().connect(path=self.exePath)
dialog = app.window(title_re="DISCLAIMER")
        if dialog.exists():
            checkbox = ButtonWrapper(dialog.TCheckBox.wrapper_object())
            checkbox.get_check_state()
            checkbox.check()
            dialog["I accept"].close_click()
```

Comment: `if dialog.TCheckBox.exists()` ? Or do you ask about `checkbox.get_check_state()` possible values?

Comment: Hello I checked if dialog.TCheckBox.exists() and it doesnt work and doesnt close the disclaimer box. Also the get_check_state will only tell me whether checkbox is checked or not.  My scenario is even if the checkbox is not present the code should work and I am looking for possible conditions via we can check. I searched for methods which tell if a checkbox is present inside a dialog box but couldnt find any.

Comment: you can search for checkbox using `try dialog.child_window(title='TCheckBox', control_type='CheckBox') except ElementNotFoundError: Pass`